# Date field keeps showing time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have a really annoying issue where I can't get the time to stop appearing in a date time field.

I send the data from this form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Progress","Order",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input name="Deadline" type="hidden" value="@Model.Deadline" />
    <input name="StatusDescription" type="hidden" value="@Model.StatusDescription" />
    <input name="Progress" type="hidden" value="@Model.Progress" />
    <input type="submit" value="progress" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Progress(ViewOrderViewModel viewModel)
{
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Progress form

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Deadline, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Deadline, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control deadlineDatepicker", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Deadline) } })
    </div>
</div>
```

ViewModel

```
[Display(Name="Deadline")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }
```

This is driving me crazy as I have already done something similar with my Order Edit form and it works fine, but I had to manually build the model there which seems pointless. How can I just display the date in the progress form without the time?

- I tried adding `DataType.Date` annotation, but this salso forces the default  browser date selector whcih don't want as I am using JQuery UI datepicker.
- I tried changing the field to `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Deadline.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")` but I get

  > Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
- I also tried `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Deadline.Date` but it still shows the time.
- Even after adding a `@value=@Model.DateTime.ToString("dd\mm\yyyy")` attribute on the form, it doesn't help... In fact setting the value in this way appears to do nothing whatsoever.
- I changed the field to `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Deadline, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}",  new { @class = "form-control deadlineDatepicker", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Deadline)} )` but the time still appears. This makes no sense

Please can someone help me with this and explain why this is so difficult?

Comment: Your `EditorFor()` in conjuction with the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute will work fine. Alternatively you can use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Deadline, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control .... })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I know it should work (it seems to in other areas of my project) but it doesn't - the time always appears as 00:00. Using `TextBoxFor` method also doesn't work -the time still displays

Comment: @Yogi The date isn't `null`, there is always a value at this point

Comment: Using `TextBoxFor()` has nothing to do with your datepicker! (it generates identical html - just add the `deadlineDatepicker` class - I just kept the code in my comment short)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I tried it again after removing my `new htmlAttributes` part, and it works fine apart from the fact that I can still see the time`00:00`, I don't get how that is possibl

Comment: Its not. I can only assume you have not shown the correct code, or you have some other code causing the issue.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can confirm that as the ViewModel is passed into the view from controller action, the date value is exactly the same as it is in my working example, so if there is something that I have left out it must be in the view .. I don't know what to do I feel like this is a constant battle with asp

Comment: Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VNaOCX) to prove both work correctly and display the date in the specified format. (its other code you have not shown us that is causing the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update**

It seems the issue is to do with the way the data was being sent to the controller.

After changing the hidden date field to

```
<input name="Deadline" type="hidden" value="@Model.Deadline.ToShortDateString()" />
```

It now works fine.

After checking the actual value once it hits the `Progress` controller, I noticed 1 difference, which is that the time value simply changed from

```
TimeOfDay   {12:00:00}  System.TimeSpan
```

to

```
TimeOfDay   {00:00:00}  System.TimeSpan
```

So passing in the time with `ToShortDateString()` causes the receiving method to process it as having a time of 00:00:00, and for whatever reason this means that the date can be displayed without any time.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me understand this behaviour.

---

**old, unnacceptable answer**

Although I hate to do this I am resorting to adding this bit of js to overcome this extremely irritating issue

```
@{ 
    var dateString = Model.Deadline.ToShortDateString();
}

<script>
    function codeAddress() {
        $('.deadlineDatepicker').val('@dateString');
    }
    window.onload = codeAddress;
</script>
```

Comment: There is no point complaining about a framework that has been thoroughly tested and works. There is no need to that code unless **YOU** have other code causing the default behavior to fail

Comment: @StephenMuecke I understand that its just that I really can't see anything I am doing. Even trying to narrow down the possiblities all I can think of is that I have some JS somewhere which specifically changes date formats but I have never added anything like that

Comment: @StephenMuecke as I mentioned it works fine on me `edit` page, which is why I am inclined to agree with you, but I genuinely can't see what is diffferent on the `progress` page - it's a very simple form and shares the same layout as `edit`. Maybe I will remove everything I can and try to recreate so that I can share it here

Comment: @StephenMuecke I found a solution to my issue I updated the answer if you are interested at all

Comment: Again, that is not necessary. If makes no difference what the formatted value is in your other view. Your binding the value to a `DateTime` property so it will be a `DateTime` when your call `return View(viewModel);` (and a `DateTime` has a time component - all you have done is make it `00:00:00 AM`). Taking a wild guess, I assume your view model property is actually `public string Deadline { get; set; }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke you don't need to guess - the view model property is in my original question and i can confirm it is of type `DateTime`. And it does seem to be necessary because without calling `ToShortDateString`, the time is displayed so I'm not sure what else I can do

Comment: No, it is not necessary.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ye well as I said in my answer I don't understand why that works, because obviously if I **did** want to show the time, then passing the time as `00:00` shouldn't just diappear. If you have any thoughts on it then I am super interested, but as you can see it isn't to do with code elsewhere affecting that view, as it should still display the midnight time if that was the case.

Comment: So why does [this DoNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VNaOCX) work and your code not? What your claiming is simply impossible unless there is other code causing the issue

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't know! But I promise you I 100% definitely don't have a script somewhere which checks if the time is midnight and then hide if it is, so I have no clue where I am supposed to start looking. every bit of code which formats dates has been set to exclude time. If some other code was causing the issue, why would it it hide the time when its 00:00?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159892/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-bassie).